# Transpose data in Google Drive Spreadsheet for chart

Tags: google-visualization, google-sheets

I am trying to debug the chart drawing functionality in Google Spreadsheet, which is part of their drive web application suite.

I have all my data in the Google spreadsheet but the initial format has the data in the wrong columns and rows. What I need is to transpose the data before feeding it into the Google chart API. For example,

```
var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('columnchart'));
chart.draw(data, null);
```

I could use the `getDataTable` function to collect the required data, but I have no idea how to transpose the data once I have collected it.

In addition, is there any way I can debug the problem, if the chart is not displaying? I tried to use the App Script but the stack that I see is the an object, not the content in the object.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want to exchange columns Or change columns to row? can you edit the spreadsheet? where are you working HTML page with JS, Google apps script, Java...

Comment: Transposing rows and columns is not supported by the Visualization API, though it is possible in some circumstances to do it manually.  You are probably better off rearranging the data in your spreadsheet to match your needs rather than trying to do it in javascript.

Comment: If, on the other hand, it is an issue of column/row order, then you can solve those by sorting to change the row order and using a DataView to change the column order.

Answer (score 0):

From http://gappstips.com/google-sheets/how-to-transpose-data-in-a-google-spreadsheet/

To transpose data from a table spanning cells A1 to E8 in a Google spreadsheet use the following method:

- choose an appropriate cell that you want the data to start in eg A10
- type in the following formula: `=TRANSPOSE(A1:E8)`
- press enter to complete your formula

The table will be transposed into the appropriate span of cells for your table.